# Singleton and NSNumberFormatter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, singleton, nsnumberformatter

Currently, I have the following code in one of my methods:

```
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
formatter.currencyGroupingSeparator?
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
```

Because I have to repeat these in various functions in different view controllers, how do I create a singleton in Swift to call for the NSNumberFormatter and avoid duplicates?

I assume that I have to create a new Swift file, but unsure of how to construct the class?

Comment: You don't need a singleton for this. You could just use a type method that vends different types of pre configured for matters and just use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

update: **Xcode 8.2.1 • Swift 3.0.2**

```
extension Double {
    static let twoFractionDigits: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return formatter
    }()
    var formatted: String {
        return Double.twoFractionDigits.string(for: self) ?? ""
    }
}

100.954345.formatted    // 100.95
```

Comment: Example of an XY question. The OP asked "how do I create a singleton". In reality, he wanted to know "how do I format a Double efficiently with very little code", and this answers it perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I'd do is make a property that is lazily instantiated. That way you will have no duplicates, and it won't be created and take up memory until you need it.

```
lazy var numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter] = {
    var _numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter]()
    _numberFormatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
    _numberFormatter.currencyGroupingSeparator?
    _numberFormatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
    return _numberFormatter
}()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and edit on my question. This works, but why not an extension since I have to refer to this in other ViewControllers?

Comment: I assumed you would be subclassing the VC this is in. You can just pair this with an extension instead if you want.

Answer (score 0):

`NSNumberFormatter` isn't that expensive (as compared to `NSDateFormatter`) but if you want to have a class method which vends a once only instantiated object

```
class var prettyFormatter:NSNumberFormatter {

        struct SingletonNumberFormatter {
            static var instance:NSNumberFormatter?
        }

        if SingletonNumberFormatter.instance == nil {
            SingletonNumberFormatter.instance = NSNumberFormatter()
            SingletonNumberFormatter.instance.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
            SingletonNumberFormatter.instance.currencyGroupingSeparator?
            SingletonNumberFormatter.instance.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        }

        return SingletonNumberFormatter.instance!
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another Singleton solution:

```
class Formatters{
    static let twoFractionDigits: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
        formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
        return formatter
    }()
    static func formatNumber(fromNumber: NSNumber) -> String{
        return twoFractionDigits.string(from: fromNumber) ?? ""
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Formatters.formatNumber(fromNumber: 100)
```

When you have a variable with types of Int, CGFloat etc, use:

```
Formatters.formatNumber(fromNumber: 100 as NSNumber)
```