# Swift NumberFormatter formatting all values to 3 decimal places?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, number-formatting

I have a large array of doubles, which have  a varying number of decimal places, such as:

```
[11307.3, 1025.64, 1.27826, 1676.46, 0.584175, 183.792, 1.02237, 13.649, 0.472665, 127.604]
```

I am attempting to format the number so there are commas every thousand and the decimal places are not formatted to a specific number such as 3dp. The array should look like

```
[11,307.3, 1,025.64, 1.27826, 1,676.46, 0.584175, 183.792, 1.02237, 13.649, 0.472665, 127.604]
```

I have tried doing this by defining NumberFormatter as such:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
```

and then choosing decimal for style:

```
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.decimal
```

The values in the array are display in a table view, and when a user taps on for example the 2nd cell, in a new screen the value 1,025.64 would be displayed.
I used this code to do that:

```
var formattedPrice = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:coinPriceDouble!))
self.coinPriceLbl.text = "\(coinTitleText!): \(Cryptocoin.instance.fiatSymbol)\(formattedPrice!)"
```

This works perfect for any value that does not have more than 3 decimal places.
 If the user chose the 3rd value in the array, it would display 1.278 not 1.27826.

Is there any way to format these values with commas but not force them to a specific number of decimal places?

Comment: `NumberFormatter` is highly customizable. Did you read the documentation and the [Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27571946/6655075 .

This solved my problem. As I had 3 values displaying, each from a different array, I would end up formatting all 3 whereas I only wanted to format 1 array.

```
   extension Double {
        static let twoFractionDigits: NumberFormatter = {
            let formatter = NumberFormatter()
            formatter.numberStyle = .decimal
            formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
            formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
            return formatter
        }()
        var formatted: String {
            return Double.twoFractionDigits.string(for: self) ?? ""
        }
    }
```

I removed

```
var formattedPrice = numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value:coinPriceDouble!))
```

And simply used

```
self.coinPriceLbl.text = "\(coinTitleText!): \(Cryptocoin.instance.fiatSymbol)\(coinPriceDouble!.formatted)"
```

Edit: As Dávid Pásztor mentioned, I only want to add the comma separator to the values which need it while still maintaining the precision of each value down to the last decimal value.

Answer (score 22):

As **vadian** said, `NumberFormatter` is highly customisable.

Just play around its properties, like (you need to customise based on your needs):

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3
```

Here the explanation for [`NumberFormatter`'s `maximumFractionDigits` property and related](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1415364-maximumfractiondigits).

Here instead a blog that explains all the related aspects of `NumberFormatter` [A Guide to `NSNumberFormatter`](http://samwize.com/2015/11/04/a-guide-to-nsnumberformatter/).

**EDIT**

Put the following code in a Playground and observe the result:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .decimal
numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 3

let formattedNumbers = [11307.3, 1025.64, 1.27826, 1676.46, 0.584175, 183.792, 1.02237, 13.649, 0.472665, 127.604].flatMap { number in
    return numberFormatter.string(from: number)
}
print(formattedNumbers)
```

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but to me it seems that OP actually wants to change the default value of `numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits`, which is actually 3 (if you test your code without setting it to 3, you get the exact same result). As per my understanding, OP actually wants to keep the precision of the values and only wants to add the decimal separator to the values, but keep the fractional part intact.

Comment: @DávidPásztor in fact mine is just an example. He/she can play with the code I’ve provided in order to find the right result

Comment: Correct @DávidPásztor . After more searching, i came across https://stackoverflow.com/a/27571946/6655075 which solved my problem, because after the segue I was displaying values from 3 arrays, and so by doing the above it formatted all 3 not just the 1 i needed.

Comment: @Jeremy if you read carefully my answer I’ve provided not the right answer but a way to figured out yours based on your needs. It’s more important to understand what’s going on instead of copy and paste from SO a solution. The playground has this purpose.

Answer (score -5):

You could try setting the maximum fraction digits to a largish number.

`numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 15`

Comment: Why `15`? The OP wants three fraction digits

Comment: kinda extreme suggestion, it covers the OP's requirement about... well... 5 times.

Comment: @LorenzoB That's the maximum number of digits, not the exact number.  Setting this property to a high number will ensure that the formatter will still use as few decimal places as possible, but never more than 15.  The default value for the property is 3.

Comment: Very confusing answer. Why 15 actually? Will 16 work too when I want 3 decimals?